# Simple current limiting regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I’m currently getting ready for an Electronic Systems Engineering exam, and going through past paper questions.

I need help with a few questions regarding the following current limited regulator.
[image]
The questions:

1. Find the zener voltage of Dz if the required regulated output is 12V.
2. Calculate the value of R for safe operation if the input voltage is 15V and the power rating of Dz is 0.5W.

My answers:
[image]

My questions to you:

1. Have I approached the first question correctly? Can you please confirm my answer?
2. In the second question: **what is a “safe” current for the zener?** Of course it should be less than the maximum current found from its power rating. But how much less? (I just randomly assumed 30mA)

Comment: On the first question, I would assume no load current, so no drop across Rd.  On the second one, you know the zener voltage and the max power, P=IV gives you the max current.  Then take 15V-Vz to get the voltage across the resistor...you know the voltage and current, R=E/I.

Comment: I would add to Cristobal's comment; assume negligible base current in Q1 when calculating the resistor.

Comment: For an exam question I would suggest using the minimum resistor value from the stated zener dissipation, and adding a note about a real design using a higher value. Your answer is better in reality, of course, especially if you consider the effect of tolerances of input voltage and zener voltage. With a 2V drop, a 5% error in each could lead to a 62% increase in Zener dissipation, so a 300mW nominal dissipation would lead to ~500mW worst-case (not counting resistor tolerance). But don't waste time on this kind of thing during an exam.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany the minimum R for 5W into Zener means the current limiter burns up the R , who cares about protecting the Zener.  Which uses less than the R in current limit mode!!  Not prudent. With a current gain of 100 using a ratio of 50 means the R loss is only 2 % more in current limit mode or using a ratio of 30 3.3% wasted power.

Comment: From 1.6 V/30 mA, how do you get 80 Ω?

Answer (score 1):

The bigger question is what V tolerance and max power is used .

- the Power rating of R needed for a short circuit output.
- This will limit your power output on Q1 with short cct.
- Zener power is a smaller issue and can operate at half power.
- hFE is a also a bigger issue for max Rbias / load R ratio. so 250 is much better than 100

**Most of the power is dissipated in the transistor, then R ( in short circuit) and then Zener ( no load)**

Assume short cct output max current of 1A then what R value = 1/4W  for a 1/2 W part.

- (1)  choose R near Zener rated voltage for 5mA or a bit more for accuracy ( not as asked for safe limit !! )
- (2) Use Re = 0.55V / I rated   (NOT 0.7V) as cutoff base current is low. Iout/hfe^2

Below 1st example is bad during a short circuit and will burn 1/4W with 2.3W

- 2nd example does not. by using near 5mA Zener bias current.
- using near 5mA typ datasheet rated current for Zener voltage of 13V.
  [image]

Comment: Simulation http://tinyurl.com/y78pfyre